# JSF Validation message displayed twice

Tags: jsf

[image]

I have a login form where I have 2 fields Username and password. Both are required fields. I also have a `<h:messages/>` tag to show the validation messages , but it is displayed in multiple locations.

*xhtml code:*

```
    User name <h:inputText id="username" value="#{login.userName}" required="true" 
    styleClass="resizedTextbox" style="align:right;" /> 

    Password <h:inputSecret required="true" styleClass="resizedTextbox"  
    id="password" value="#{login.password}" />
    <h:messages style="font-size:1.1em;color:red;text-shadow: 0 1px #2a85a1;"/>

    <p class="submit">
      <h:commandButton id="login"
        action="#{login.login}" value="Login">
      </h:commandButton>
    </p>
```

*ManagedBean code:*

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,                     
                                    "Login details are incorrect", "Check username and password");
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null, message);
```

I tried using `<h:message for=""/>` and adding the client id in FacesMessage but I see the same issue.
 Can somebody help?

Comment: So you have multiple `<h:messages>`?

Comment: Maybe you should show the code just above the login form.

Comment: There is nothing much ! Just a couple of divs and h:form

Comment: What about refreshing & redeploying the project ?

Comment: Refreshing the page?

Comment: Post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). The cause of the problem is not visible in the information provided so far. The symptoms at least tell that you've two `<h:messages>`. If I were you, I'd just have explored the HTML DOM to figure where exactly it is being inserted and then trackback it in the template.

Comment: @BalusC: I am using JSF 2.0 (Mojarra) with Facelets. I had a look at the generated code using Developer tools. I am able to see <ul><li>,,.</li></ul> tags in place of the <h:messages/> tag but i have only 1 <h:messages/> tag in the file

Comment: @Omar: Ok, I will try that out !

Comment: @Omar; I don't know how but it seems to be working after redeploying! What might have been the issue?

Comment: @user2017810, _rarely_, some little modifications on the view pages are not saved and taken into consideration in the server, that's why refreshing/redeploying the project solves usually the problem.